# jquery: unable to find elements from jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fetching HTML string and I want to construct a jQuery object from it and then perform operations but I am getting `undefined`.

```
    var data = '<h1>Hi World</h1';
    var html = '<div id="rendered">'+data+'</div>';
    //var content = $($.parseHTML(html));
    var content = $.parseHTML(html);

    console.log($(content).find('#rendered').html()) // it says undefined
```

Comment: Can you replace `content` with html in the last line and try again? I feel like content is already a jquery element from the second last line and you are redeclaring again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` is used to look for *child* elements. `#rendered` is the parent node in the HTML structure you create, so `find()` doesn't return anything. You need to use `filter()` instead as that includes the current node when searching.

Also note that `$.parseHTML()` isn't required - jQuery does this automatically when you provide a HTML-formatted string to the jQuery object contructor.

```js
var data = '<h1>Hi World</h1';
var html = '<div id="rendered">' + data + '</div>';

console.log($(html).filter('#rendered').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```